# How to remove Emoji from String

Tags: c#, string

i hope you can help me. I try to do an exercise on a website and I need to clean strings, but It doesn't work.

```
 public static string Clean(string identifier)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(identifier);

    
    for(int i = 0; i < builder.Length; i++) {
        if(Char.IsWhiteSpace(identifier, i)) {
            builder[i] = '_';
        }

        if(Char.IsSurrogate(identifier, i)) {
            builder.Remove(i, 1);
        }

        if(builder[i] == '-') {
            builder.Remove(i, 1);
            char toUpper = Char.ToUpper(builder[i]); // i since we've removed the char before
            builder[i] = toUpper;
        }

        if(Char.GetUnicodeCategory(identifier, i) == UnicodeCategory.OtherLetter) {
            builder.Remove(i, 1);
        }
    }
    builder.Replace("\0", "CTRL");

    return builder.ToString();
}
```

Everytime I try to delete an Emoji with the if(Char.IsSurrogate)... It just replaces the Emoji with an "?".

Does anybody know a solution?

Comment: Hint: You can make your life much easier by *only copying the good characters into a new, empty StringBuilder*, instead of trying to *remove the bad characters*. The problem with the latter approach is that as soon as you remove the character at position 5, the (yet unprocessed) character at position 6 moves to position 5, yet your loop continues at (new) position 6, ignoring a character that should have been processed.

Comment: Well it's an exercise to clean up identifier names and I've got to keep rules.

Comment: You should use an If/else first testing for unicode and then if not unicode try utf8.

Comment: @Bekobiii: I don't think you're breaking any rules that way. **How** you clean the identifier name is an implementation detail. If you want to keep your current approach, you need to change your code so that you only increment `i` if nothing has been removed.

Comment: Let's make sure of your background understanding of the problem first. In your own words, what does `(Char.IsSurrogate)` actually mean, and how does it help you detect the emoji? When you remove an emoji, how many elements do you think should be removed from the string? Why?

Comment: An emoji takes two characters. You need to remove both

Comment: Well If I delete both characters and we have for example 3 emojis in our string after each other. The last one won't get deleted.

I've tried this.

`builder.Remove(i, 1)`
`builder.Remove(i, 1)`

Double since you said an emoji takes two characters.

Comment: You are still skipping the next char, that now moved into the i position

Comment: Yeah I got it working. Replaced the for-loop with a switch statement and only increase i if I don't delete a char.